# CKEDITOR : How to restrict default space adding after and before BR tag when use GetData method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor 4.x version. when I get the data from editor using

getData method now I have two files before editor file and after editor file

when I comparing the both files the after editor file has some spaces in after and before **BR** tag

I am using editor.getData(); method

Before Editor :

```
<span class="Nocharacterstyle" data-name="[No character style]">Osteriaalla <br> Frasca</span>
```

After Editor :

```
<span class="Nocharacterstyle" data-name="[No character style]">Osteria
            <br />
            alla Frasca</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's working fine now. Please see both links

[https://forums.asp.net/t/1992574.aspx?CKEDITOR+is+adding+extra+line+breaks+br+paragraph+p+and+spaces+every+time+after+saving](https://forums.asp.net/t/1992574.aspx?CKEDITOR%20is%20adding%20extra%20line%20breaks%20br%20paragraph%20p%20and%20spaces%20every%20time%20after%20saving)

https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting